# Sync sqlite db in phone from mdb in network location, is it feasible?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app installed in mobile phone. What I want to do is, when user connects the phone and go to sync screen of the app and click on sync, I want to access mdb file from pc.

is it feasible?

-- Edit --

Here is an example scenerio:

I have an existing desktop application in vb that is using .mdb file as database installed in lap top.

I have created an android app to use some of the features of the app to android. since android doesn't support mdb, I've converted the important tables to sqlite database and using the same while showing android app

Now I want some automated way to sync the sqlite db in single way as android app is read only.

we can use a button in desktop app to sync db in phone but I don't want any manual work from user.

Not sure what is the best way to deal with this

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm...  In the past, Access and *.mdb has not really played well with others.  One solution would be is to add a insert/update timestamp column to each of the tables within your Access database.

When your phone needed to sync (a property somewhere on your phone based on connection, time of day, phase of the moon, etc), it would send your laptop VB the timestamp of it last sync point.

The VB app would scan all of the tables that needed to snyc, looking for inserts/updates/deletes (soft) and send back to your mobile app, all rows that occurred after your sync point.

Once your mobile app has accepted and applied all of the updates, it would update its sync point timestamp.

This would require you to create a service within your VB app that would accept a service call with a timestamp as a parameter and being able to return rows of an indeterminate length and quantity.

Now, this solution forces the sync processing on your mobile app versus your original requirement that the laptop VB app do the synchronization.

Comment: problem with web service is, you have to code in both mobile app and in the desktop app, I just want to create a new console app in laptop that will manage the update. Timestamp is good idea, another question is, will my console app be able to access sqlite database in mobile?

Comment: No, because SQLite on your phone is not a database server.  It is not listening on some port for a SQL query request to come in.  In a number of ways, it is like MS Access in that it is designed for single user, local access, data storage that can be retrieved through the SQL language. Or are you looking to access the underlying SQLite file on the mobile phone?